# VBA matching in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have to compare sheet 1 and sheet 2 : two column.

If both of the column matches in both sheet 1 and 2 then it will display to sheet3 , showing the match. Unfortunately, I am only able to match one column and then display to sheet 3.

here is my code:

```
Sub FindMatches()

    Dim Sht1Rng As Range
    Dim Sht2Rng As Range

    Set Sht1Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B65536").End(xlUp))
    Set Sht2Rng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H1", Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H65536").End(xlUp))

    For Each c In Sht1Rng
        Set d = Sht2Rng.Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not d Is Nothing Then
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = c.Value
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = c.Offset(0, 2).Value
            Set d = Nothing
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: if you want to check 2 columns you can do the samething you did here....similar to the D variable create a new variable and add the find function for the second column.... then add an and condition in the if statement.

Comment: If you are using `"B65536"` to represent the last cell in the column, don't. Use `Worksheet.Rows.Count` instead as this will give the correct last cell and doesn't depend on the version of Excel.

Answer (score 3):

In order to show the results in "Sheet3", you need that both columns in "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" will have the same value.

Therefore, you can use `Application.Match`, it will simplify and shorten your code a lot:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindMatches()

    Dim Sht1Rng As Range
    Dim Sht2Rng As Range
    Dim C As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Sht1Rng = .Range("B1", .Range("B65536").End(xlUp))
    End With
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Set Sht2Rng = .Range("H1", .Range("H65536").End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each C In Sht1Rng
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(C.Value, Sht2Rng, 0)) Then ' <-- successful match in both columns
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = C.Value
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = C.Offset(0, 2).Value
        End If
    Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: it works when comparing just one column. My data are: 

Sheet 1:

Column1:           Column2:
ID                         Amount
123                          32
132                          45
1234                        50

Sheet2:
Column1:           Column2:
ID                         Amount
123                          0
132                          45
1234                        50

My display on sheet3 should display:
132                          45
1234                        50

Answer (score 1):

I have added an imaginary `Sht2Rng2` to your code. Now, if a match is found in `Sht2Rng` a second search is made in `Sht2Rng2` and the value written to Sheet3 only if this second one is also found. Tweak the definition of `Sht2Rng2` as required.

```
Sub FindMatches()

    Dim Sht1Rng As Range
    Dim Sht2Rng As Range, Sht2Rng2 As Range
    Dim C As Range, D As Range
    Dim R As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Sht1Rng = .Range("B1", .Range("B65536").End(xlUp))
    End With
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Set Sht2Rng = .Range("H1", .Range("H65536").End(xlUp))
        Set Sht2Rng2 = .Range("J1", .Range("H65536").End(xlUp))
    End With


    For Each C In Sht1Rng
        Set D = Sht2Rng.Find(C.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not D Is Nothing Then
            Set D = Sht2Rng2.Find(C.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not D Is Nothing Then
                With Worksheets("Sheet3")
                    R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Cells(R, 1).Value = C.Value
                    .Cells(R + 1, 1).Value = C.Offset(0, 2).Value
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next C
End Sub
```

You should add `Option Explicit` at the top of your code sheet and declare all variables. It will, one day, save you many, many hours of pulling your hair.